# How to concatenate strings in an html attribute using ejs?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to make a link to a random file using ejs template engine. I have a javascript string variable named randomProject which is in a file called "case". However, I don't know how to concatenate these 2 strings together.

I have tried to use "plus" sign as in `<a href=<% "/case/" + randomProject%>>` but it did not work.

index.ejs (before I wanted to make a random link)

```
<a href='/case/portfolio-website'>
    <h2>Portfolio Website</h2>
</a>
```

index.ejs (after I wanted to make a random link, which does not work now)

```
<a href=<% "/case/" + randomProject%>>
<h2><%= randomProject %></h2>
</a>
```

main.js

```
const projects = ['gochiso','junction','portfolio-website','tedx-flyer','tedx-website','thirty-logo-challenge']
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * projects.length);
const randomProject = projects[randomNum]
```

directory

```
case
  gochiso.ejs
  portfolio-website.ejs
  thirty-logo-challenge.ejs
  junction.ejs
  tedx-website.ejs
```

Comment: did you try `<a href="/case/<%= randomProject %>" >`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of ways you could concatenate:

Using `template literal`

```
<a href="<%= `/case/${randomProject}` %>">
```

Regular `ejs` to output escaped html

```
<a href="/case/<%= randomProject %>">
```